# Want to use Quickblox like mbaas to make a video Chatroulette function

Tags: quickblox, mbaas

I read the code of video example.
It's based on chat room, need register to chat room first then start video 1:1 chat with selected user id.
But for a senario of chatroulette, I need find a random available video ready user, is this achivable by the sdk? I need the user repeated video chat with random user, so did for the peer user.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to implement "chatroulette":

1. When user starts app first time, you need to register him behind the scene, or by using your form - as you wish. Next time he will log in automatically by saved credentials (from registration).
2. After log in, user will try to enter in pre-defined chat room. If room doesn't exist yet it will be created.
3. After entering room request all users, logged in your room, and choose random user to call.

Comment: Thanks for comments Alexey. Could you be more specific on the 3rd steps? How to choose random user? I can get all the user list right? But how do I know the random user I choose is not in process of video chat with another user?

Comment: QBChatRoom have object method - (void)requestOnlineUsers; It will request list of online users in this room. Then you can get random user the way like this:
NSInteger userIndex = usersArray[arc4random()%usersArray.count];
NSInteger userId = usersArray[userIndex];

Now you can request QBUUser by obtained userId.

If user in call progress now you should implement auto call rejecting and get another user again.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But got error of "Room is locked. Please configure" when called createOrJoinRoomWithName. Do you have any commenst on this error?